# Multiple select onChange JS function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to run a function when someone adds another option in a multiple select.

I am using `onchange="attributePrice(this.value)"` but after the second attribute (option) i add the alert shows only the id of the first option selected.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.change()` method of jQuery

```
$('#select_id').change(function(e){
    val = $(this).val();
});
```

Here you will get `comma(,)` seperated selected value